# Is there the difference between 'jump you' and 'jump at you'?

Tags: grammar, meaning

Is there the difference between **jump you** and **jump at you**? I am asking since I see the same translation  of them from the context.

> She looked at him, scowling with an anxiety she did not like to admit
>   to herself, at the fresh rips in the knees of his blue jeans, the
>   streaks of dirt grained deep in his shirt, a darkening bruise on the
>   cheekbone under his left eye. “Okay, did the big boys **jump you** in the
>   schoolyard this time, or when you got off the bus?”

A WIND in the DOOR by Madeleine L’Engle

and an another example:

> Maybe you were surprised that I didn't jump at you

Comment: This is *[jump](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/jump_1?)* in the sense of a sudden attack. You can get jumped even if no one jumps on or jumps at you in the process.

Comment: "Jump [someone]" is probably considered *informal*, if not quite *slang* anymore.

Comment: In all fairness, that dictionary does imply an on: [transitive, intransitive] jump (on) somebody (informal) to attack somebody suddenly
The thieves jumped him in a dark alleyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"Jump you"** Is a slang term, and it essentially means the same thing as "Ambush", or to attack a person when they weren't expecting to be attacked.  It is frequently used when someone attacks you to steal something.  [Source](https://www.quora.com/What-do-people-mean-when-they-say-theyre-going-to-jump-someone)

**"Jump at you"** is not as much of a slang word.  It means to jump in your direction.  However, even though it's not a slang word, it is frequently used metaphorically.

For something to "jump out at you" might mean that you noticed it instantly as though it was jumping up and down and everything else was still.  [Source](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/jump-out-at)

To "Jump at something" can mean to try to approach or obtain it as fast as you can.  It is as though you jumped out of your starting position in order to get to it instead of more leasurly approaching it.  [Source](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/jump+at+the+opportunity)